# Is it possible to create a software to find formal proofs?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, computability, axioms, proof-theory

Let's say I have a Hilbert style system, with a few axioms and rules of inference, and I want to find a proof for some formula $\varphi$, is it possible to create an algorithm that would find a proof for it with the given system (guaranteeing it'd be in finite time)?

I know a bit of programming, but I think answering this question goes beyond my abilities.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving

Comment: Yes. But *finite* does not mean *practical* or even *before the end of the Universe*

Comment: A proof is a certain type of sequence of words. List all possible sequences, check for each whether it is a proof, and whether it ends in $\varphi$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "guaranteeing the program terminates on all inputs" ?  If a program ends, it will always be in finite time.

Comment: The wording of your question is unclear: what is the algorithm to do if presented with an unprovable input? Also, if you are only interested in propositional logic, then please state that in your statement of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can only find proofs for any given valid formula, if your calculus is complete.
Under the precondition that your calculus is complete, it is possible to create an algorithm that will terminate for every valid formula.
However, if your language is undecidable (e.g. first-order logic), you cannot find an algorithm that will terminate for every (valid and non-valid) formula.

Comment: I'm looking for an algorithm just for propositional logic, using the standard language ($(\{p_0,p_1,\dots\},\{\neg,\wedge,\vee,\rightarrow\},\{(,)\})$), could you provide some sources about your statement?

Comment: A proof always has finite length. By induction on the string length (you first create strings of length 1, then of length 2, then of length 3, and so on) and checking if the strings are proofs you can eventually find a proof. This is essentially what "André Nicolas" already stated in his comment.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD : in propositionnal logic, everything reduces to boolean functions $B^n \to B$, so your proof program reduces to computing boolean functions (and checking they are equal), this should be less than $100$ lines of code with simple recursive functions and data structures (binary trees)

Comment: @user1952009: Your statement is correct; however, the question is how to find a Hilbert-style proof. I think your statement doesn't cover that aspect.

Comment: @Xaver : I'm not convinced that a complete set of rules for the propositionnal logic can be fundamentally different to the boolean operations rules, isn't there an isomorphism between the two ways to write proofs ?

Comment: Yes, but note that OP is not asking for an algorithm that *decides* whether something is a theorem of a theory $T$ or not (which would require that $T$ be, well, decidable). S/he is asking whether there's an algorithm that will say "Yes, that's a theorem, alright, because here's a proof" when given a theorem as input; but it's ok if it never halts when given a non-theorem (because it won't find any proof). For any semi-decidable theory $T$, including arithmetic and set theory (PA and ZFC), there **is** such an algorithm. <cont>

Comment: <cont> Your last sentence is  correct, but I'd just add this footnote: For a semi-decidable theory, even if it's not decidable, there *is* an algorithm which will terminate for every valid formula, and won't terminate for non-valid formulas.

Comment: It is *not* true that only complete theories are decidable: if you add an uninterpreted constant symbol, $c$, say, to the signature of a decidable theory like the theory of [real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field), the resulting theory is decidable but not complete. Given a sentence $\phi$, $\phi$ is valid iff $\forall x\phi[x/c]$ is valid in real closed fields, but the sentence $c = 0$ is neither valid nor unsatisfiable.